Create oracle database docker container for raspberry pi 4 (arm64)
I hope I'm in the correct forum.
I desperately try to create an docker image with an oracle database that runs on my raspberry pi.
There are some resources in the web with an step by step guide how one can manage this. (for example: https://www.database-blog.at/2023/06/28/oracle-19c-fuer-linux-arm-ist-da/)
I successfully create an Dockerfile with an base setup like this:
FROM arm64v8/oraclelinux:9
RUN dnf -y update
RUN yum install -y oracle-database-preinstall-19c.aarch64
RUN mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
RUN chown -r oracle:oinstall /u01/app
...
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

The problem is that the installation of oracle-database-preinstall-19c.aarch64 fails with the error message: No match for argument: oracle-database-preinstall-19c.aarch64
When I try to search for it with yum search -y oracle-database-preinstall-19c.aarch64 i just get the error:
Oracle Linux 9 EPEL Packages for Development (aarch64)      1.8 MB/s |  58 MB     00:32    
Oracle Linux 9 BaseOS Latest (aarch64)                      1.7 MB/s |  35 MB     00:19    
Oracle Linux 9 Application Stream Packages (aarch64)        1.8 MB/s |  20 MB     00:11    
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:21 ago on Sat Apr 20 08:30:05 2024.
No matches found.

So I have no idea what Im doing wrong. Is there a special repo I have to include to install the needed package? Is the packet not hosted anymore? Or is is just not possible to create an docker image with an oracle database for an arm/aarch architecture?
Any help is appreciated.
UPDATE
I think I got it. It seems that I have to add the repo with yum-config-manager. In my case (ol8) it was: yum-config-manager --add-repo https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL8/baseos/latest/aarch64.
After this, dnf -y install oracle-database-preinstall-19c seems to work.
UPDATE #2
It seems not possible to do this with an raspberry pi 4. But it worked with an raspberry pi 5 first try! Thanks to tiv for pointing out, and also Ignace Nguyen Anh Tuan for his patience.

The Oracle documentation here uses oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el8.aarch64.rpm with oraclelinux:8.

Unfortunately when I try yum -y install oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el8.aarch64.rpm i got the error Can not load RPM file: oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el8.aarch64.rpm. Could not open: oracle-database-preinstall-19c-1.0-1.el8.aarch64.rpm. Ich changed my base image to oraclelinux8 and even tried an yum update before.

In the past, I use this approach, RP4 + Oracle Linux + Oracle RDBMS database 19C arm64. The installation Oracle Software is good but after installation, the step create database is hanging because the listener is broken pipe. This is the Oracle internal error.

Last week, I have RP5 with 8M RAM, boot on SSD M2 NVME 1Tb, network
USB Ethernet 2.5G, raspberry pi OS bookworm + docker + Container
Oracle RDBMS Database 19.19 arm64 (6G for download) from Oracle
container website . It works and works very well and easy to do.
I launch a stressing test with swingbench schema SOE 150G, my RP5 held up well. The test is during one hour, the CPU never exceeded 50%.
Regards.


Can you please give me the link for the particular arm image from the container website?

Hi,  you create a oracle account (free), you connect to https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:5718305704368:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:9,9,Oracle%20Database%20Enterprise%20Edition,Oracle%20Database%20Enterprise%20Edition,1,0&cs=365eihkTLq-_PbGrQRbvdUQhzAZnGeY5HQQoVKlZ4-3elsJcxDecTi6OUjN5x9QAK2GcZJx77a0uIHC26hLNbwA  at end of page you have the tag for container arm64 Oracle database

Hi, i followed your Tutorial but now i also got the error  Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe. I used the mentioned image. Any further help is appreciated. Maybe you can provide your full docker run command?

Hi, did you use raspberry pi OS? Which version Oracle container you use? Could you give me how you create your database ( the command docker with options, parameters).

Hi, I use ubuntu 23.10 and the image container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.19.0.0. I try to create the container with: docker run -d --name foo -p 1522:1521 -p 5501:5500 container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.19.0.0
. This container crashes soon after the start. Docker logs results in following output: TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00517: Lost contact
Linux Error: 32: Broken pipe

Hi, I am using raspberry pi os (bookworm). I know somebody use ubuntu but the version is not same. I copy the link maybe help you : https://mkc110891.medium.com/oracle-19c-on-ubuntu-18-04-docker-6898cd2916f9

Thanks for your effort. I will give it a try :)

Hi Ignace, glad to see you here, still playing with oracle ! Best, Marc.

Hi Marc, how are you?

You can't run Oracle19 on RP4, but you can on RP5.
See https://medium.com/p/54201d68b431

That's it. It is just not possible. Thanks.
